# How to set qml property from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "BackEnd.h"
#include "Execute.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

And my main.qml

```
Window 
{
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 280
    height: 570
    property var prop;
}
```

How can i set the `prop` property from c++? I found only solutions to create a qml object from c++.

Comment: [Interacting with QML Objects from C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

Comment: But I have no `Item`

Comment: In QML every declared thing (be it `Window`, `Item` or `MyFancyObject`) can be given properties and signals

Comment: My main.cpp now loke like: ```` int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("com.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");
    qmlRegisterType<Execute>("com.execute", 1, 0, "Execute");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    QObject *object= component.create();
    object->setProperty("prop", 500);
    delete object;


    return app.exec();
} ````  but this doesn't work

Comment: @JohnSmith Do not add code in the comments, this information should be part of your question so you should do an edit

Comment: Ok. Now if i have a `QObject` created, how can I display it?

Comment: @JohnSmith In the code that you show in the comments you are creating a component that has nothing to do with the view that shows QQmlApplicationEngine, what you should do is create a QObject that has as Q_PROPERTY that reflects the data you want to modify, export it to QML using setContextProperty, and finally make a binding in QML as indicated in the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#pushing-references-to-qml

Comment: @JohnSmith A complete example for your case can be found at the following link: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/0c0468a621d64e7f828010e4cf4d2347

Comment: But I don't want assign a new object, rather i want change an existing value, it is created in the qml file. Is this possible? For example I want change the color of a rectangle to green, it was before red.

Comment: @JohnSmith I have created an object that interacts with the other existing element and sets the value. I have updated the example.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. If you write your example in an answer I can mark the question as solved